# Add "copy TO [SE-site]" to the Area 51 accounts tab

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, profile-copying, related-accounts

Currently, the Area 51 accounts tab has a "copy from" button, while all other site's accounts tab have a "copy [sitename] profile to related accounts". Since the Area 51 profile is the only complete listing of a user's profiles (including private betas), the ability to copy the Area 51 profile *to* another site seems to be missing.

Also, so the "copy Area 51 profile to related accounts" to overwrite all profiles would be nice.

*(I'm introducing the [related-accounts] tag here, since that's what it's named at the accounts tab)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We updated the Area 51 accounts page to resemble other accounts pages accross the network:

- Flair is displayed in a grid (not a list)
- "Copy profile from" button replaced with "Copy profile to"
- The "About Me" section supports markdown

Comment: thanks. Is there any way to sync only two profiles however?

Comment: @tobias copy-paste :/

Comment: ♦: I thought so... What about adding a small "<=" arrow in that grid with a "copy this profile here" as tooltip? Yeah, I know it's not so important and can be worked around, was just an idea...

Comment: @tobias perhaps, but that'd be a feature request for the entire network of sites

Comment: realted [Copy profile link is too obscure](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66196/146482) (I didn't do it!)