# Copy profile link is too obscure

Tags: discussion, status-completed, profile-page, profile-copying

There is a copy profile to associated accounts link ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/462382?tab=accounts#tab-top)), but that is way too obscure.

I think it should be moved to (or another link shown at) a more prominent place, like the profile editing screen.

Answer (score 4):

The next build will add a "save and copy profile to all Stack Exchange network accounts" link next to the Cancel button on `/users/edit`, which does exactly what it says.

Comment: any chance of renaming the `Copy profile to all Stack Exchange network accounts` to `Save and copy profile to all Stack Exchange network accounts`? I have just edited my profile and the current two buttons (save... & copy...) *made me think*. *"Does the copy also do a save or should I save first and then copy?"* I used save first to be sure not to loose my changes, had to come back in and copy. I can imagine other users making the same mistake too.